# Apple developer Enroll with Two-Factor Authentication for a developer account that is no on any device

Tags: ios, icloud

As everyone else, I got the notice from apple to enable 2 factor authentication.
When trying to do so, I managed for my devices that all have the same account, but couldn't do it for my developer account as it is deferent from the my personal (devices) account and it seems that you have to do do it from a device and not strait from the iCloud account on a browser.
It is so weird as Apple was the ones that suggested that we use a deferent account for personal and developer accounts.
Any Ideas on how to fix this? I can't develop any more, as i don't have access to my account.
10x

Comment: [ios multiple iCloud accounts](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ios+multiple+icloud+accounts&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8); [Mac multiple iCloud accounts](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&ei=lAyOXLaACe_Vz7sPn5SQiAw&q=mac+multiple+icloud+accounts&oq=mac+multiple+icloud+accounts&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30l2j0j0i8i7i30j0i5i30j0i8i30l4.41367.41641..42346...0.0..0.165.479.0j3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i8i7i10i30j0i7i5i30.bDz1BdlT9KQ)

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know why did i lost a point but in any case, found the solution that worked for me.
As i needed the account only for setting 2 factor authentication:

1. I couldn't authenticate by adding the developer iCloud account while using the private account
2. found an old device that i'm not using anymore
3. removed the private account and used the developer account
4. did the 2 factor authentication with the phone number of my regular device
5. did the 2 factor authentication for the developer account on the browser

Now everything is working.
10x